# $http is not a function (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I made sure $scope is before $http, but I'm still getting this error!

```
angular.module('management')
    .service('Requests', function () { /* ... */ })
    .controller('RequestsOffWork', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 
                                  'Authentication', '$http', 'Requests',
        function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, $http, Authentication, Requests) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the parameters out of order.

> '$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', '$http', 'Requests'
>
> $scope, $stateParams, $location, $http, Authentication, Requests

Switch `$http` and `Authentication` in one of the two spots.